# knockoutjs checkbox and click on parent td

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a table with a row. The row has a TD(with a checkbox in it) and on the TD I have a click function. So that when the TD is clicked the checkbox will get checked/unchecked.

It works fine when I click on the TD , but when clicking on the checkbox the (visual) value of the checkbox does not change( It does not get checked/unchecked )

The wanted situation is:

1. When I click the checkbox, the (visual) value of the checkbox changes and I can call a function.( for example to make an AJAX call )
2. When I click on the TD, the (visual) value of the checkbox changes and I can call a function. ( for example to make an AJAX call )

How can we achieve this?

[Sample Code](http://jsfiddle.net/Eatdh/5/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid the click event issues, use the `label` element to make a larger area clickable. Here I've made the label a block element so it takes up the whole `td`:

```
<td>
    <label style="display: block">
        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: checkBox" />
    </label>
</td>
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/mbest/LsxSh/

Comment: Thanks !! This does the trick. I have edited a little by adding a click function. [http://jsfiddle.net/LsxSh/4/](http://jsfiddle.net/LsxSh/4/)

Answer (score 11):

The problem is that the click handler for the `TD` fires also when you click the `checkbox`, which means the `checkbox` gets changed by both the default click handler for the `checkbox` and your custom click handler for the `TD` (they counteract each other). The solution is to prevent clicks on the `checkbox` from bubbling to the `TD`. You can do this in Knockout with this binding: `click:function(){return true}, clickBubble:false`.

Here it is in action: http://jsfiddle.net/mbest/Eatdh/12/

I do think, however, that using a `label` is a better approach (see my other answer).

Comment: I prefer this because it prevents additional HTML clutter.

Comment: `label` might be a better approach for the scenario in the question, but this is precisely the solution I needed because my click handler's on the entire `tr`.

Answer (score 1):

Td Event seems to be overriding the the input's check click event

Answer (score 0):

clicking the check box invokes the click hander code for the td:

```
self.checkBox(!self.checkBox());
```

this removes the check.

Comment: True, now the question is how can we avoid this. I specify what exactly I'm looking for in the first post.

Comment: Yeah :P... It wasn't properly formed.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't quite DRY, but its quick and functional: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sSkK4/)

```
<td data-bind="click:tdClick">
      <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: checkBox, click:tdClick" />
</td>
```

Comment: Here's an alternate method that also works: Change data bind on checkbox to `checked: checkBox,click:function(){return true;},clickBubble:false`. In yours the checkbox gets checked then unchecked and then checked again when you click on it.

Comment: @MichaelBest I think that's the best solution so far. Why not post it as an answer?

Comment: Right. I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: Thanks, this one works also. And I also think Micheal Best answers is the best approach.